# Node Red - if in function node doesn't working correctly

Tags: function

I'm new to Node Red.
I have this block of code in function node (On message tab):

```
var totale = "inizio";
var messaggio = msg.status.text;
if (messaggio === true) {
    totale = "abc";
}
```

Why the "if" doesn't work if the status of node is "true"?
The text node output is always "inizio", never "abc"

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkxpS.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please check the input message msg.status.text. If it's not a boolean true, but a string "true", then the equality check will fail. In that case, you should use something like this

```
var messaggio = msg.status.text;

if (messaggio === "true") {
    msg.payload = "abc";
} else {
    msg.payload = "inizio";
}

return msg;
```

Comment: Solved, it works